# Why is the exprected value of a sum of RV following a Z-distribution not equalt to 0?

Tags: r, random-generation

I am using R to draw a thousand of RVs from a Z-distribution.
I noticed that the expected value of their mean is as expected ~0 (magnitude 10^(-4)) sometimes positive, sometimes negative but; the sum of their mean is significatively far from 0. Why?

`mean(colMeans(replicate(n = 1000, expr = rnorm(n = 1000, sd = 1, mean = 0))))`

Or

$E((E[X])) = 0$

And

`sum(colMeans(replicate(n = 1000, expr = rnorm(n = 1000, sd = 1, mean = 0))))?`

Or

$\sum E[X] != 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem confused about what an expectation is. It's not the same thing as a sample mean.

What you have demonstrated is not that the expectation is different, but rather than the variability is different -- the expectation is actually 0 for both cases but the variance is much larger in the second case (indeed, the variance is a million times as big), so naturally the first is generally closer to zero than the second.

If you simulate each repeatedly you'll see that they both scatter around 0 but the `sum` one just has a bigger spread.
[image: stripchart of output of 100 simulations of OP's code for the mean and sum]

Zooming in on the upper one:
[image: stripchart of 100 simulations of just the mean one]
As we see they're both scattered around 0 but the sum is just more spread out.